# Caught behind by wicket Keeper - Who takes strike?

Tags: rules, cricket

If the batsman is caught behind by the wicket keeper and the non-striking batsman runs and reaches the batting end, does the batting end change?

In our match the batsman was out caught behind, and the other batsmen just reached the batting end before the catch was taken and hence the umpire allowed the change of batsman to play. But as per my experience the new batsmen should take the strike.

Answer (score 5):

There is no special case for being "caught behind" or "caught by the wicket keeper", so the rule is the same as at any other time: if the batsmen had crossed at the moment the catch was taken, then the former non-striker takes strike. If the batsmen had not crossed, then the new batsman takes strike.

Specifically, see Law 18.12(a):

> When a batsman is dismissed Caught [...] the not out batsman shall return to the wicket he has left but only if the batsmen had not already crossed at the instant of the incident causing the dismissal.