# Who will take strike for a batsman being out in the middle of an over?

Tags: rules, cricket

How is it decided who should take strike after a wicket?

Comment: Taking or giving stick is to be hassled or criticised. The question still makes no sense, it's just a statement about this observation. The title uses "strick" though, which is probably meant to be "strike", and who takes strike after a wicket is kind of important. Going to look for duplicate.

Comment: Ah, good stuff. [This question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12821/caught-behind-by-wicket-keeper-who-takes-strike) isn't a duplicate per se, but my answer there covers this one.